# Haskell QuickCheck for testing n-ary tree eval

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a n-ary tree defined as follows:

```
data Tree = Leaf1 | Leaf2 | Tree ([Tree])
```

and I have a function

```
eval :: Tree -> int
```

which returns the winner (`Leaf1` indicates that player one won, `Leaf2` indicates that player two won)

I've been trying to write a test for `eval` using [QuickCheck](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck) but I  can't seem to understand how it works for recursive data types and how to write tests for this function